# How can I make asynchronous request with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my Laravel 5.4 web app user can request report generation that takes a couple of minutes due to a big amount of data. Because of these he couldn't work with application no more, until report will be generated. To fix this problem I have read about [queues in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues) and separated out my report generation code to the job class, but my app still holds until report will be generated. **How can I fix that?**

To be absolutely clear I will sum up my problem:

1. User make request for report generation **(my app absolutely holds at this moment)**
2. My app receives POST request in routes and calls a function from the controller class.
3. Controller's function dispatches a job, that should generate report and put it into the client web folder.

Comment: What queue driver are you using?

Comment: @Jerodev I have read that queues can be used without any drivers, am I wrong?

Comment: In that case, you are using the `sync` driver. Take a look at my answer about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Laravel uses the `sync` queue driver. This driver executes the queued jobs in the same request as the one they are created in. So this won't make any difference.

You should take a look at [other drivers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#introduction) and use the [Laravel queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker) background process to execute jobs to make sure they don't hold the webrequest from completing.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have already pretty much solved the problem by introducing a queue.  Put the job in the queue, but don't keep track of its progress - allow your code to continue and return to the user.  It should be possible to "fire-and-forget", and then either ask the user to check if the report is ready in a couple of minutes, or offer the ability to email it to them when it is completed.

Comment: Thanks for reply! And how can I make it? Now, all I have put into the controller is: `dispatch(new job_to_be_done_class());`